# How to combine the types into one type using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to combine types into one type for the code below,

```
type Mode = {
    mode: 'new' | 'edit'
}

type Item = {
    id: Scalars['ID'],
    description: Scalars['string'],
}

type FormControllerProps = {
    data: Item[];
    initialValues: Partial<Item> & Mode & {id?: string}; //how to rewrite this
}
```

Now as you see for type FormControllerProps i am using Item, Mode and id for initialValues field.
how can i rewrite the initialValues field type such that Item, Mode and id are in one type

could someone help me with this.  I am new to using typescript. thanks

Comment: `type InitialValues = Partial<Item> & Mode & {id?: string};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i get your question correctly, but you can composite types like this:

```
type ItemWithMode = Item & Mode;
```

also note that your Mode and Item should both be interface, not type.