# Using useState hook with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, use-state

I wanted to know if I it's possible to use inheritance while setting the useState type. What I mean is if have an interface like that:

```
interface PackageItem {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    address: string
}
```

And another interface like that

```
interface Selectable {
    selected: boolean
}
```

Now I want to create a state where I will have an array of selectable packages,
so I tried something like this:

```
const [selectablePackages, setSelectablePackages] = useState<(PackageItem extends Selectable)[]>();
```

But I keep getting an error, which highlights the extends word, saying:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

I'm not setting the state type correctly, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `const [selectablePackages, setSelectablePackages] = useState<PackageItem[]>();` No need to specify what it extends. Hopefully the error message was pointing you to the character that caused a syntax error?

Comment: @JuanMendes, but I also what it to have the `selected` property. I don't want to add to the `PackageItem` in general. I want it to be selectable only in the current component.

Comment: Then you meant to use `&`. `<PackageItem & Selectable)[]>`. Consider just creating a separate type.`type SelectablePackageItem = PackageItem & Selectable`

Comment: Consider updating the title of your question since it has nothing to do with `useState` specifically. That will help others find this if they have a similar problem.  Maybe something like: "Combining types with TypeScript".  I probably should have marked your question as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566121/how-to-combine-the-types-into-one-type-using-typescript-and-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine the types into one type using typescript and react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566121/how-to-combine-the-types-into-one-type-using-typescript-and-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to create an inline type which can be done using `&`, [the intersection operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types)

```
const [selectablePackages, setSelectablePackages] = 
    useState<(PackageItem & Selectable)[]>();
```

Consider using a type or interface if you need to use it in multiple places.

```
type SelectablePackageItem = PackageItem & Selectable

// Or interface
interface SelectablePackageItem extends PackageItem, Selectable {}

const [selectablePackages, setSelectablePackages] = 
    useState<SelectablePackageItem[]>();
```